# QML - make my Scene3D item not clickable

Tags: 3d, qml

In QML I have an object displayed in 3D with a Scene3D QML type, but I can click and move it with my mouse.

I would like it to not be clickable, it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, I added the following to my Scene3D item :

```
enabled: false
```

It prevents any mouse event